# Can $a + bX + cX^2 \overset{D}{=} X + X^2$ for a continuous random variable $X$ and $c\neq 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ a continuous random variable. Can it happen that
$$a + bX + cX^2 \overset{D}{=} X + X^2,$$
while $c\neq 1$?

My intuition is that no (if the equality holds, then $c=1$). I figured that e.g., $a$ is uniquely given from other constants by $a = (1-b)\mathbb{E}[X] + (1-c)\mathbb{E}[X^2]$. 
Maybe looking at higher moments can help, but I didn't explore it much.

Comment: $E[X]$ and $E[X]$ do not have to be finite numbers

Comment: @Henry thats true. We can make a similar argument with medians. But it would be still nice to see at least that $c$ has to be 1 under some light assumptions on $X$ such as moment existence.